# Integrate Twilio Verify app with Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

[image]

Step 1: We successfully uploaded the files and made all the necessary adjustments to the basic policies ( SignUpOrSignin.xml and TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml)

Step 2: We successfully uploaded the StepUpPSD2 files after making all the necessary changes to the custom polices.

Step 3 - An error occurred when uploading the SignUpSignin custom policy.

error:

```
Validation failed: 3 validation error(s) found in policy "B2C_1A_PSD2EXTENSIONS" of tenant "ifitech2bc.onmicrosoft.com".
User journey 'SignUpOrSignIn' in policy 'B2C_1A_PSD2Extensions' of tenant 'ifitech2bc.onmicrosoft.com' has 2 sendClaims steps. 
Please specify a DefaultCpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId attribute set to the default issuer technical profile reference id.User journey "SignUpOrSignIn" in policy "B2C_1A_PSD2Extensions" of tenant "ifitech2bc.onmicrosoft.com" has step 4 with 2 claims exchanges. It must be preceded by a claims provider selection in order to determine which claims exchange can be used.User journey "SignUpOrSignIn" in policy "B2C_1A_PSD2Extensions" of tenant "ifitech2bc.onmicrosoft.com" has step 5 with 2 claims exchanges. It must be preceded by a claims provider selection in order to determine which claims exchange can be used.
User journey 'SignUpOrSignIn' in policy 'B2C_1A_PSD2Extensions' of tenant 'ifitech2bc.onmicrosoft.com' has 2 sendClaims steps. 
Please specify a DefaultCpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId attribute set to the default issuer technical profile reference id.User journey "SignUpOrSignIn" in policy "B2C_1A_PSD2Extensions" of tenant "ifitech2bc.onmicrosoft.com" has step 4 with 2 claims exchanges. 
It must be preceded by a claims provider selection in order to determine which claims exchange can be used.
User journey "SignUpOrSignIn" in policy "B2C_1A_PSD2Extensions" of tenant "ifitech2bc.onmicrosoft.com" has step 5 with 2 claims exchanges. 
It must be preceded by a claims provider selection in order to determine which claims exchange can be used.
```

Please check the detailed error in the screenshot as well.

We tried all the possible changes in the files and to upload the same, but it did not work out.

Basically we want to integrate Twilio Verify app with Azure Active Directory B2C.

Comment: What screenshot? You need to upload the files somewhere so they can be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by an existing user journey with the same id : `SignUpOrSignIn`. It creates duplicates of the same step when the journeys are merged. Remove the `SignUpOrSignIn` journey from the Trustframeworkbase file.

See this, same error: [Azure AD B2C TOTP sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290477/azure-ad-b2c-totp-sample)